# Why can a member function be called on a temporary but a global function cannot?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

In the below code I call `step` as a member function and as a global function on a temporary value. The member function is allowed, and works, whereas the global function is disallowed due to `invalid initialisation of non-const reference of type ‘kludge&’ from an rvalue of type ‘kludge’`.

I'm trying to understand, from a language perspective, why one behaviour is allowed and the other is not. Technically both calls and functions seem like they'd be compiled identically, or at least could be.

```
#include <iostream>

struct kludge {
    int a;
    kludge() {
        a = 1;
    }

    kludge & step() {
        a++;
        std::cout << a << ",";
        return *this;
    }
};

kludge get() {
    kludge t;
    return t;
}

kludge & step( kludge & t ) {
    t.a++;
    std::cout << t.a << ",";
    return t;
}

int main() {
    get().step();
    step( get() );
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You cannot bind rvalues to non-const lvalue references<sup>1</sup>. That applies to `step(get())` as the parameter of `step`, which is a non-const lvalue reference, cannot be bound to the prvalue (*pure rvalue*) `get()`.

However, member functions can per se be called on object arguments of *every* value category, be it lvalue or rvalue - [over.match.funcs]/4 and /5:

> For non-static member functions, the type of the implicit object
>   parameter is
>
> - “lvalue reference to *cv* `X`” for functions declared without a *ref-qualifier* or with the `&` *ref-qualifier*
>
> [..]
>
> For non-static member functions declared without a *ref-qualifier*, an
>   additional rule applies:
>
> - **even if the implicit object parameter is
>     not `const`-qualified, an rvalue can be bound to the parameter as long
>     as in all other respects the argument can be converted to the type of
>     the implicit object parameter.**   [ *Note:* The fact that such an
>     argument is an rvalue does not affect the ranking of implicit
>     conversion sequences (13.3.3.2). *— end note* ]

But if you use so-called *ref-qualifiers*, you can restrict the value categories that are valid for a particular member function. That is, if you write:

```
kludge & step() & { /* .. */ }
```

The call `get().step()` will be ill-formed too.

---

<sup>1</sup>)
This is a well-known fact, but here is [dcl.init.ref]/5, heavily shortened:

> A reference to type “*cv1* `T1`” is initialized by an expression of
>   type “*cv2* `T2`” as follows:
>
> - If the reference is an lvalue reference and the initializer expression
>
>   - is an lvalue [..]
>   - has a class type (i.e., `T2` is a class type), where `T1` is not reference-related to `T2`, and can be implicitly converted to an lvalue of type “*cv3* `T3`,”
>       [..]
> - **Otherwise, the reference shall be an lvalue reference to a non-volatile `const` type (i.e., *cv1* shall be `const`), or the
>     reference shall be an rvalue reference.**

Comment: Do you know the relevant clauses in the standard that state these two rules?

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y Yes. Do you want them too?

Comment: Yes, please. I enjoy understanding things to the spec level, and got tripped up following this one.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y Beware: The quote for the first fact is very long and complicated, it goes beyound this answer perhaps.

Comment: I'd expect nothing less of the C++ standard. :)
You can just show paragraphcs numbers and a one-line snippet if you want. I can refer to the standard for the full context.

Answer (score 1):

Temporary cannot bind to non-const reference

```
step( get() );
//    ~~~~~   Creates a temporary object (r-value)
// But step( ) excepts a non-const reference
```

Comment: Note that both calls are being made on temporary objects, not just this one.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y yes but the other one is okay, non-static member functions can be called on temporaries too

Comment: @P0W OP knows that. His question is *why* that is.